Strange compiler error using vector4 initializer
This is an odd one:
let m1 = simd_float4x4(1)
let m2 = simd_float4x4(1)
let v = simd_float3(1, 1, 1)
let vv = vector4(v,1)
//print(m1 * m2 * vector4(v,1)) // will not compile
print(m1 * m2 * vv) // compiles

In the above, the two print statements are doing the same thing, but the first presents the error:
Cannot convert value of type 'simd_float4' (aka 'SIMD4<Float>') to expected argument type 'float4x4' (aka 'simd_float4x4')

Why does this happen?

I cannot reproduce on Xcode 16.1, Swift 6.0.

@Sweeper Ah. At the moment I’m forced to use Swift 5 so maybe it was a compiler bug they fixed.

@Sweeper Swift 6.0 and Xcode 16.0 give me this error still. I'll upgrade to 16.1 out of curiousity.

I switched to Swift 5 language mode and it still compiles. Could this be something else in your project that's causing this? Does this happen in a new project?

@Sweeper Thanks for the help. I also suspected that so I created a new command line project and pasted in just the above code with import simd and I get the same error set to Swift 5 or 6. Weird.

I just updated to Xcode 16.1 but the error remains on a new project with nothing other than the code above.

I am not sure that matrix and vector can be multiplied. It may just be that the operation is not handled in Accelerate. You may have to define the * operator using the matrix_multiply function

@PtitXav Yes they can be multiplied, and the version that compiles demonstrates that. Here is the existing documentation that shows it is fine: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/simd_float4x4/2914260
